# Is "management" section not allowed in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to add users to IIS Manager via `web.config`, but whenever I add the following lines, the web site stops working and says `web.config` is not valid.

The web site works if I add those lines in `administration.config`, but I like to keep the scope small by sticking with `web.config`.

```
<system.webServer>
  <management>
    <authorization defaultProvider="ConfigurationAuthorizationProvider">
      <authorizationRules>
        <scope path="/MyApp">
          <add name="domain\user" />
        </scope>
      </authorizationRules>
    </authorization>
  </management>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Google search can answer your question.

[IIS Management element](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/management)

From that page:

> Note: The settings in the management element can only be configured in the Administration.config file.